# How to use blurha.sh with new Next.JS Image Component

Tags: next.js

Any idea how to use, in Next.JS 11, the new blur placeholder from Image component as announced on https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#image-placeholders ?

```
<Image
 src={banner}
 alt={name}
 layout="responsive"
 width={1920}
 height={675}
 quality={100}
 placeholder="blur"
 blurDataURL={bannerBlurHash} // Here bannerBlurHash code as data url ?
 priority
/>
```

Cheers,

Comment: You need to use a third party library like [`plaiceholder`](https://plaiceholder.co/docs/usage) if your banner is dynamic. If it is an `StaticImage` (i.e. `import banner from '../some/src'` then Next.js will automatically generate the blurDataURL for you. This issue tracked the new Next.js 11 feature that you've mentioned. It is worth a read if you are looking for other solutions: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18858

Answer (score 2):

I built a quick utility to generate the data URL for a blurhash from an input image and to play with the blurhash parameters. The resulting data URL can be used as Next.js Image's `blurDataURL`

(Still a work in progress, but it's functional)

https://blurred.dev

Answer (score 2):

I just have created a custom hook that solves this problem. [It's here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-next-blurhash).

You just will need to do something like this:

```
const [blurData] = useNextBlurhash(bannerBlurHash);
```

And then pass the `blurData`to your image

Answer (score 0):

You need a backend service that generates a `blurHash` for every dynamic image.
I don't think there's an easier way then generating a canvas with something like BlurHash's [typescript client](https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash/tree/master/TypeScript) then turn the canvas to `dataURI` with [`.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).